# jQuery Ajax header not being passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request-headers

I want to send an AJAX call to a service with a couple of custom headers. While the request goes successfully, the headers are not being sent. The following is my code snippet:

```
func123: function (params) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/",
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Contract": "1",
                "Vector": "abc",
                "Authorization": "xyz"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
    },
```

Comment: Does it work if you take it out of the promise?

Comment: Also, how do you know they aren't being sent?

Comment: Try removing the / at the end of the url. Any different?

Comment: @AdrianLynch: 
It's the same even if I take it out of the promise. 
Removing the "/" didn't make any difference.

I am looking at the request being sent through Fiddler. In the Headers section, the only thing present is under Miscellaneous, wherein the keys of the headers are present in lowercase as a comma-separated list. Like this:

Miscellaneous
Access-Request-Headers: contract, vector, authorization

No values associated with any of them.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Fiddler. What if you run it in a page and view the request in dev tools?

Comment: It shows up in dev tools. Yet, the service returns an error stating that required headers are missing.

Comment: Nope. Just returns a failure.

Comment: Could it be CORS related? What server are you hitting?

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with promises or Bluebird and the title is quite misleading in that regard.  This is a question about sending custom headers with an ajax call.

Comment: Any word on what happened? I am having similar issues. Just including a header key/val in ajax call and printing all headers in local node app. Headers are not being passed.

Comment: @Nathan822 Were you able to fix this problem?